# Add series to only the first row in a DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

i have a series of tickers of the S&P500 constituents (ticker). I want to add all the tickers to my DataFrame (SP) within the column Ticker and within the row of the 2021-01-22.

[image]

So just copy all the tickers into one cell, like this:

```
SP = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date': "2021-01-22", 'Ticker': ['MMM,ABT,ABBV,...','NaN','NaN']})
SP

    Date    Ticker
0   2021-01-22  MMM,ABT,ABBV,...
1   2021-01-22  NaN
2   2021-01-22  NaN
```

I have tried `SP.at[0, 'Ticker'] = ticker` , but it did not work.

Comment: you want all the tickers in the same row?

Comment: All tickers in the same cell.

Comment: Ok, so you want all the list of ticker in the row of Date = '2021-01-22' with the column name Ticker, Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly! All tickers in the row of the mentioned date within the column Ticker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can do this way

```py
ticker_list = list(ticker.values)
SP.iloc[5494,1] = ', '.join(ticker_list)
SP
```

Here I have just made a list of ticker values and appended it to the row you want.
By seeing your image, your row for date '2021-01-22' seems to be 5494.

Answer (score 0):

Create SP Data frame with Date Field

```
SP = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date': ["2021-01-22","2021-01-21","2021-01-20"]})
```

Create Ticker Column with 'NaN' Value

```
SP['Ticker']='NaN'
```

Create Ticker Data frame - **You can ignore this step if you are converting list to data frame in order work on this requirement**

```
Ticker=pd.DataFrame(['MMM','ABT','ABBV','...','NaN','NaN'])
```

Convert Ticker data frame column data into list and assign it to Ticker column in SP data frame

```
SP['Ticker'][0]=Ticker[0].tolist()  #From Data Frame
```

**OR**

```
Ticker  = ['MMM','ABT','ABBV','...','NaN','NaN']
SP['Ticker'][0]=Ticker              #From pre-defined list  

display(SP)
```

Comment: I have turned my list (ticker) into a DataFrame and tried to add it to SP['Ticker] as a list, but i always get an error: KeyError: 0. I have copied your code

Comment: When you are assigning list to column of data frame it will read each list item as a row value and it will throw you an error if no. of list items counts not matching with no. of rows in data frame. Here, I have created empty column and assigned list to first cell of the column. i.e., SP['Ticker'][0], zero indicates first cell.